# Docker - ASP.NET Core and SQL Server Script

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to use ASP.NET Core and SQL Server on nginx Linux based container .

i want to run the database script to create my table , but I am not sure how to do it . Its failing , and with the ENTRY POINT its starting the service which get executed even before the SQL Server is started and before Script being executed.

How can I install ASP.NET Core and SQL Server image in the same container?

My docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk  AS build
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/output .
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
COPY SqlCmdStartup.sh SqlCmdStartup.sh
COPY 01-createSpeakerTable.sql 01-createSpeakerTable.sql
COPY 02-createSponsorTable.sql 02-createSponsorTable.sql
RUN chmod +x SqlCmdStartup.sh
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
CMD ["/bin/bash","entrypoint.sh"]
#CMD /bin/bash entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT["dotnet","ConferenceApp.dll"]
```

Entrypoint.sh:

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & SqlCmdStartup.sh
```

SqlCmdStartup.sh:

```
sleep 20s
export STATUS=0
i=0
while [[ $STATUS -eq 0 ]] || [[ $i -lt 30 ]]; do
    sleep 1
    i=$i+1
    STATUS=$(grep 'Server setup is completed' /var/opt/mssql/log/setup*.log | wc -l)
done

/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Your_password123 -d master -i 01-createSpeakerTable.sql
```

createSpeakerTable.sql:

```
GO
Create DATABASE [DockerDBTest]
GO
USE [DockerDBTest]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Speakers]    Script Date: 13/10/2018 12:41:44 ******/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Speakers]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Speakers]    Script Date: 13/10/2018 12:41:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Speakers](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [First] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Last] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**my *docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3'

services :
 api:
   image: conference/api
   container_name: conference_api
   build:
    context: .
   ports:
   - 5000:80
   environment:
     ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Production
   depends_on :
    - db
 db:
   image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
   environment:
           SA_PASSWORD: "Your_password123"
           ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
           MSSQL_PID: Developer
   ports:
    - 5432:5432
    - 1433:1433
```

When I am trying to run , its saying /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr  not found and its not creating DBase and Table

my sql server and asp.net app is not running on the same container ? . I want to run the DB Script first and then start the service

Comment: 1) why do you want to have website and db in the same container? 2) how do you work with db in code, are you using db first with ef core?

Comment: @ingvar I want datapersistent in the same container for my webapi and want the SQL to reside within the same container , I am not using code first , as there will be few static data in a table with the predefined state which will be used during the time of initialization of my application.

Comment: Any advance? I only managed to use SQLite instead of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure below will allow you to create database and many other things, including database seeding:

docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_db"
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
    environment:
     - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
     - SA_PASSWORD=<sa user password here>
     - MSSQL_PID=Developer
    volumes:
      - ./sqlserver-logs:/var/opt/mssql/log
      
      # Make sure the script contains valid Unix line endings only
      - ./sqlserver/sqlserver_init.sh:/sqlserver_init.sh
      - ./sqlserver/create_database.sql:/create_database.sql
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    entrypoint: /opt/mssql/bin/nonroot_msg.sh
    command: /sqlserver_init.sh
```

sqlserver_init.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x

###################################################################
# Remember to save this file in LF (Unix) line format (no \r)
###################################################################

echo "Starting the SQL Server in the background"
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
BACKGROUND_WORKER_PID=$!

echo "Waiting for the SQL Server to start"
until /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -Q "select 1"
do
  echo "Waiting for the SQL Server to start"
done

echo "Initializing db"
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -d master -i /create_database.sql

# Do not exit the docker image
wait $BACKGROUND_WORKER_PID
```

create_database.sql:

```sql
USE master
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '<your db name>')
BEGIN
  CREATE DATABASE <your db name>;
END;
GO
```